# $X_1$ is a set of numbers which are neither prime nor composite. $X_2$ is a set of numbers from 1 to 40 that are multiples of 10. Find ($X_1\cup X_2$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X_1$ is a set of numbers which are neither prime nor composite. $X_2$ is a set of numbers from 1 to 40 that are multiples of 10.

> Find $X_1 \cup X_2$).

---

When I tried I got the answer as $\{1,10,20,30,40\}$
There is only one number which is neither prime nor composite, i.e. $1$ **[I didn't know it included $0$]**
$\Rightarrow X_1 = \{1\}, X_2 = \{10,20,30,40\}$
$X_1 \cup X_2 =  \{1,10,20,30,40\}$.

But in the book it is written:
There is only one number which is neither prime nor composite, i.e. $0$
$\Rightarrow X_1 = \{0\}, X_2 = \{10,20,30,40\}$
$X_1 \cup X_2 = \{0,10,20,30,40\}$.

> *So, can you help me with this? Thanks.*

Comment: Could you make sure you're talking of integer or even natural numbers?

Comment: Not even natural numbers

Comment: The question just says 'numbers' so i think it is non negative numbers

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ is neither orime nor composite ...

Comment: I am sure they meant integers

Comment: The empty set is a set of numbers that are neither prime nor composite. So is $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: NON NEGATIVE INTEGERS

Comment: The book, if it says what you say it says, is wrong. $1$ is neither prime nor composite.

Comment: What book is that? It seems to be assuming the weird and unstandard "fact" that 1 is either prime or composite.

Comment: Besides this, without specifying clearly what are "the numbers" the question is seriously ill-posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is simply mistake - someone printed $0$ instead of $1$ in the answers. And then your solution is correct.
(But this explanation becomes more improbable if the answer mentions $0$ more than once. Then I believe it's even bigger author's mistake - in thinking instead of typing.)

Number $1$ is usually excluded from primes because of uniqueness of natural number factorization ("Every number can be expressed as product of primes in only one way, if order is unimportant") - because number $1$ as prime would allow many different factorizations like $2=1\cdot 2=1\cdot 1\cdot 2=\ldots$

Also the context - primes and compounds - usually doesn't include number $0$ (maybe only as reminder).

Comment: You may be correct. thnx